# Change the host header based on cookie

Tags: nginx

I want to replace www with beta in the `$http_host` if a cookie SHOW_BETA is set to true in the request.

I've put this in my host block but not sure how to do the actual replacement.

```
map $http_host $cookie_SHOW_BETA {
    // replace www with beta here if true.   <---- Question: what to put in here
    default $http_host;
}
```

also if I want to use `if` where I can easily split `$http_host` I cannot use and to check the cookie's value.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `map` has issues:

- The "from" value for the map should be first, and the variable to set should be second
- Using `$http_host` as a variable to set might not work

I don't think replace is even possible in `map`.

The best you could try is to add a prefix:

```
map $cookie_show_beta $http_host {
    true beta.$http_host;
    default $http_host;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help especially the map part, but the part beta.$http_host wouldn't give me what I want. I'm starting to think perhaps map is not what I'm looking for, I just thought map is the way to do it that's why I used it.

Comment: I think nginx does not have a feature that would do what you want.